# Linear regression using Gradient Descent

Tags: python, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I'm facing some issues trying to find the linear regression line using Gradient Descent, getting to weird results.
Here is the function:

```
def gradient_descent(m_k, c_k, learning_rate, points):
    n = len(points)
    dm, dc = 0, 0 
    for i in range(n):
        x = points.iloc[i]['alcohol']
        y = points.iloc[i]['total']
        dm += -(2/n) * x * (y - (m_k * x + c_k))  # Partial der in m
        dc += -(2/n) * (y - (m_k * x + c_k))  # Partial der in c
    m = m_k - dm * learning_rate
    c = c_k - dc * learning_rate
    return m, c
```

And combined with a for loop

```
l_rate = 0.0001
m, c = 0, 0
epochs = 1000

for _ in range(epochs):
    m, c = gradient_descent(m, c, l_rate, dataset)

plt.scatter(dataset.alcohol, dataset.total)
plt.plot(list(range(2, 10)), [m * x + c for x in range(2,10)], color='red')
plt.show()
```

Gives this result:

- Slope: 2.8061974241244196
- Y intercept: 0.5712221080810446

[image]

The problem is though that taking advantage of sklearn to compute the slope and intercept, i.e.

```
model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True).fit(np.array(dataset['alcohol']).copy().reshape(-1, 1),
                                                 np.array(dataset['total']).copy())
```

I get something completely different:

- Slope: 2.0325063
- Intercept: 5.8577761548263005

[image]

Any idea why? Looking on SO I've found out that a possible problem could be a too high learning rate, but as stated above I'm currently using 0.0001

Answer (score 2):

Sklearn's LinearRegression doesn't use gradient descent - it uses Ordinary Least Squares (OLS) Regression which is a [non-iterative method](https://www.saedsayad.com/gradient_descent.htm#:%7E:text=Ordinary%20least%20squares%20(OLS)%20is,and%20predicted%20values%20is%20minimized.&text=Gradient%20descent%20finds%20the%20linear%20model%20parameters%20iteratively.).

For your model, you might consider randomly initialising m, c rather than starting with 0,0. You could also consider adjusting the learning rate or using an adaptive learning rate.

Comment: Shouldn't they converge to the same result though? Even using 10_000 epochs both m and c get stuck at a wrong result after 1_000 reps.